# Rails: how to represent user follow user relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model-associations

I have a class `User` and I would like to implement the **follow relation** (as in twitter).
In my model a user can follow a set of other users, and also can be followed by a set of users.

In the database, there are two tables: `User` and `Follow`.

`Follow` has `src_id` and `dst_id`, both foreign keys to the `User` table. An entry in the follow table means that user with id=src_id is following user with id=dst_id.

I am having difficulty expressing this in the actual models...
thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relationship like Twitter followers/followed in ActiveRecord](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397920/relationship-like-twitter-followers-followed-in-activerecord)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#cha-following_users

For a more expansive friendship model where users can request to be friends, show pending friends etc. you could try this gem https://github.com/raw1z/amistad and this is a really good tutorial on how to get it working: http://keighl.com/post/amistad-friendships-controller

Hope that helps!