# Rails 4: setting up many to many (follower and followed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to set up a many to many relationship between `User` and `User`, where users have many followers and also follow many.

I created a pivot table via a model called `Follow`, this is the migration file:

```
class CreateFollows < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :follows do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id, index: true
      t.integer :followed_id, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  add_index :follows, [ :follower_id, :followed_id ], unique: true
  end
end
```

However, I can't get to define the `has_many`. I tried doing this:

`user.rb`:

```
has_many :followers, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name: "Follow"
has_many :followed, foreign_key: "follower_id", class_name: "Follow"
```

`follow.rb`:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
end
```

However when trying to add a user to the followers or followed collection like this `@user.followers << @user_to_be_followed` I am getting an type error that saying `Follow` is expected, not `User`. Makes sense.

But how can I define `has_many` saying that the model should be `User` but the foreign keys are called as defined and the table is `follows`?

How can I achieve this?

**Edit** searching around I stumbled on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397920/relationship-like-twitter-followers-followed-in-activerecord) an looks like the way I did it is correct...

Comment: Have you considered using [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower)

Comment: I didn't know about that one. But know that I made the effort I would like to do it the way I am trying. Especially when it looks like I did it right

Answer (score 0):

> *Note that I have changed `Follow` to `Subscription`. Follow is a verb not a noun which makes it really awkward as a model name.*

When using has_many though you both have to set up a relation to the join model and a `has_many through: :join_relation` to get a direct relationship to the other model. This case is kind of special since  User has a double relationship to `Subscription`.

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # This looks kind of weird but we have to tell Rails how to find the
  # correct foreign_key for both of the relation types
  has_many :subscriptions,
    foreign_key: :follower_id

  has_many :subscriptions_as_followed,
    class_name: 'Subscription',
    foreign_key: :followed_id

  has_many :followed,
    class_name: 'User',
    through: :subscriptions,
    source: :followed

  has_many :followers,
    class_name: 'User',
    through: :subscriptions_as_followed,
    source: :follower

  # Subscribes to another user
  def follow!(other_user)
    subscriptions.find_or_create_by(followed: other_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: The [other question you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397920/relationship-like-twitter-followers-followed-in-activerecord) only sets up a relation to the join model.  You would have to do `user.following.first.user` which is ridulous. We can do better than that.